# Sound card problem after upgrading to 13.04

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, soundcard

I upgraded Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 and the sound card isn't working anymore

any help ?

Comment: Please edit your question with more information. 1. Do you see a speaker icon on top right? 2. If so, please tell us what does the sound settings indicate. In a terminal type `lspci` and copy the results into your question. We don't know what kind of sound card you have. So no one can answer your question.

Comment: HDMI or analog audio? There are 2 likely solutions: look at post numbers 2 and 4 [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2140051&p=12627015)

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```